# Websockets on Openshift

Tags: java, websocket, jboss7.x, openshift

My web app failed to deploy on Openshift with an xml parser exception complaining *unexpected element 'enable websockets' encountered* in the jboss-web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    ​<jboss-web>
​       <enable-websockets>true</enable-websockets>
​    </jboss-web>
```

**Question:** How to configure JBoss AS 7 on Openshift to use websockets ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know JBoss AS 7 doesn't support websockets. You might want to have a look at WildFly since it's a Java EE 7 implementation.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was doing. On wildfly websockets compile fine (the jboss-web.xml above isn't needed there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is correct in the sense that the [schema for jboss-web.xml](https://github.com/jboss/metadata/blob/master/web/src/main/resources/schema/jboss-web_7_1.xsd) does not allow for a element names 'enable-websockets', in fact it has no mention of websockets. Did you check if standalone.xml allows for that or may be there is a different config file.

Comment: In fact, openshift supports JBoss AS 7.1 which uses jboss-web_7_1.xsd while my local JBoss EAP 6.3 installation uses jboss-web_7_2.xsd which allows for the websocket tag. This indicates that JBoss AS 7.1 doesn't support websockets at all (in accordance with  James R. Perkins' comment).